# Package ANE on OSX cannot find framework

Tags: macos, apache-flex, adobe, package, native

I'm trying to package an ANE (Adobe Native Extension) for Mac OS X.
I've managed to do it before, but I can't remember how.

My adt command line:

```
adt -package -target ane out/com.yprgames.maclib.ane in/extension.xml -swc in/com.yprgames.maclib.swc -platform MacOS-x86 -C in MacLib.framework
```

gives the following error:

```
no such file /Users/Yvon/MacLib/in/MacLib.framework
```

The `in` directory contains:

```
drwxr-xr-x  6 Yvon  staff   204 18 aug 13:03 MacLib.framework
-rwxrwxrwx  1 Yvon  staff  2064 17 mei 12:49 com.yprgames.maclib.swc
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Yvon  staff   444 18 aug 14:25 extension.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 Yvon  staff   897 15 mei 12:05 library.swf
```

and this is the `in/extension.xml` file:

```
<extension xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.6">
  <id>com.yprgames.maclib</id>
  <versionNumber>1</versionNumber>
  <platforms>
    <platform name="MacOS-x86">
      <applicationDeployment>
        <nativeLibrary>MacLib.framework</nativeLibrary>
        <initializer>MacLibInitializer</initializer>
        <finalizer>MacLibFinalizer</finalizer>
      </applicationDeployment>
    </platform>
  </platforms>
</extension>
```

What could be the problem? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be wrong line endings.
The script file containing the `adt` command line was created on a Windows machine, and contained \r\n endings. On the Mac the \r was taken to be part of the last file name in the command line.